# (p)_j notation in the paper Castaño-Martínez and López-Blázquez (2005)

Tags: chi-squared-test, non-central

I am trying to implement few equations for the distribution of Chi square from the paper [Castaño-Martínez and López-Blázquez (2005)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02595410). In equation (5.1), I don't understand what $(p)_j$ means. Could you please explain this notation to me? Thanks

Comment: Subscription access required. That doesn't rule out answers, but answers are much more likely if you gave a paragraph or so so that the notation could be seen in context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect it is the Pochhammer symbol: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html